# EF Core query to get all records with a date column greater than server date

Tags: mysql, linq, datetime, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0

I have a requirement to get all the records from my MySQL table by comparing a column in my table (datetime type) to be greater than the MySQL server time.

My MySQL query is like this

```
string countQuery = "Select * from features where enddate > now();";
```

The above query would give me a list of records that have date column enddate value > the mysql server date time value.

Please can someone help me translate this to an EF Core linq statement ?
I have a valid dbcontext and model class object that I would like to run this linq statement on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is some pseudo code as I'm taking a guess at column names etc.

```
var results = dbcontext.Features.Where(i => i.EndDate > Datetime.Now).ToList();
```